# How to conditionally change custom attribute's property using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-attribute

I have 3 input types. One textbox, two dates. I am setting up a custom attribute itself in the HTML as `data-ischanged = false`. In the change function, I am making it `true`. After saving the data (ajax call). I am trying to change the custom property to `false` once again. But I am unable to do so.

Any help will be appreciated.

HTML

```
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <input type="text" id="SelectedLookupTypeDescription" data-ischanged="false" />

                    <label style="padding:12px 12px">Eff. Start Date</label>
                    <input type="date" id="SelectedStartDate" data-ischanged="false" />

                    <label style="padding:12px 12px">Eff. End Date</label>
                    <input type="date" id="SelectedEndDate" data-ischanged="false" />
```

OnChange function below :

```
$('#SelectedLookupTypeDescription').on('change', function () {
    $('#SelectedLookupTypeDescription').attr("data-ischanged", true);
});

$("#SelectedStartDate").on('change', function () {
    $("#SelectedStartDate").attr("data-ischanged", true);
});

$('#SelectedEndDate').on('change', function () {
    $("#SelectedEndDate").attr("data-ischanged", true);
});
```

After the successful ajax call, using the below code I am trying to set the value to false

```
          var descselector = document.getElementById('SelectedLookupTypeDescription');
                descselector.setAttribute("data-ischanged", false);

                var StartSelector = document.getElementById('SelectedStartDate');
            StartSelector.setAttribute("data-ischanged", false);

                var EndSelector = document.getElementById('SelectedEndDate');
                EndSelector.setAttribute("data-ischanged", false);`
```

AJAX  Code

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Reference/UpdateLookupTypeData',
        data: { TypeData: TypeData },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('X-XSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken); },
        success: function (RefResponse) {
            toastr.success("Data saved successfully");
            getOtherDetails(Id);

                //var descselector = document.getElementById('SelectedLookupTypeDescription');
                //descselector.setAttribute("data-ischanged", false);

                var StartSelector = document.getElementById('SelectedStartDate');
            StartSelector.setAttribute("data-ischanged", false);

                var EndSelector = document.getElementById('SelectedEndDate');
            EndSelector.setAttribute("data-ischanged", false);
           }
        });
```

Comment: Why not use `$('#SelectedLookupTypeDescription').attr("data-ischanged", false);` in the latter code?

Comment: can you show us your ajax code, because this code looks fine

Comment: @David, i tried that way.but it is not working

Comment: How are you checking if they've changed?  I'm assuming you're *not* using `$("#SelectedEndDate").data("ischanged");` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m, i am using that

Comment: Out of interest, why do you use `$("#SelectedEndDate").attr("data-ischanged", true);` then `document.getElementById('SelectedStartDate').setAttribute("data-ischanged", false);`  why not use the same method on both:?

Comment: Ah, well there's your issue `.data()` only reads the attr once - then it caches the result.  If you're using `.data()` then *always* use `.data()` - there's multiple answers that explain it better.

Comment: @because, after the change , i need to save the data. After save, i have to moify the property. Can you provie any code sample over here of your suggestion

Comment: No, I mean you set `true` with `.attr("data-ischanged", true);` why not set `false` with `.attr("data-ischanged", false);`?   (won't work if you're reading with `.data` but seemed odd to use jquery for true but vanilla for false.

Comment: I've seen better answers that explain it, but here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30543817/2181514

Comment: I got the answer from the previous one. Thanks for your help

Comment: @freedomn-m, if you wrtite it down as an answer. I will accept it

Answer (score -1):

Try the values to `"false"` not `false`

Comment: TRied it. Did not work